# Is there a way to programatically create an imageview object based on xml definitions?

Tags: android, attributes, imageview

Essentially I want the src, tint, layout:width, layout:height, alpha etc. to be defined in an XML file, and then do a "new ImageView()" based on the XML.

Comment: Um, use a layout resource.

Comment: and how do I create the imageview using the layout resource? I don't want to use a layout inflater

Comment: "I don't want to use a layout inflater" -- why? It does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: hmm... So I should create the ImageViews in a Layout resource. Then use an inflater and access the particular imageview I need. Is that how it I should handle it?

Comment: Correct. If the layout resource is simply the `ImageView`, the `LayoutInflater` will return the `ImageView` that you need.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a layout resource that describes your `ImageView`, then inflate it with a `LayoutInflater`. In general, try to use a `LayoutInflater` that you get from an activity or fragment via its `getLayoutInflater()` method, so that styles and themes get applied the way you might expect.

Nothing else built into Android offers what you want, though one could certainly implement their own "inflater of layouts" that read in XML and created corresponding widgets.